# Check to see if checkboxes are check and then check another checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a web page which has 6 checkboxes on it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" class="chkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" class="chkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3" class="chkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk4" id="chk4" class="chkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk5" id="chk5" class="chkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk6" id="chk6" class="chkbox"/>
```

Using jquery how can I check to see if all of these 6 checkboxes are checked and if all 6 are checked check checkbox number 7:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk7" id="chk7" class="chkbox"/>
```

I have started to write the function but not sure if this is the best way to do this:

```
    function AllSectionsChecked {
        var isChecked1 = $('##chk1').attr('checked')?true:false;
        var isChecked2 = $('##chk2').attr('checked')?true:false;
        var isChecked3 = $('##chk3').attr('checked')?true:false;
        var isChecked4 = $('##chk4').attr('checked')?true:false;
        var isChecked5 = $('##chk5').attr('checked')?true:false;    
        var isChecked6 = $('##chk6').attr('checked')?true:false;                    
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am guessing its pretty much straight forward but just looking for the best way to accomplish this in jquery.

UPDATE:
***The ids and names are created dynaically and may not be in any order or scale so an id maybe chk51 and the next one maybe chk205, Appologies I should have put this in my original post ***
Thankyou for your suggestions so far.

many thanks

Comment: There seems to be six boxes, as number three occurs twice ?

Comment: yes correct just a typo on my part appologies

Comment: I think you accidentally put double `#` signs too

Comment: For my code (Coldfusion) the double hash sign is correct as there is an output tag which wraps around this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ID of the last checkbox should be `chk7` and not `chk5` ?

```
$('#chk7').prop('checked', $('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(6):checked').length == 6);
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/E6pF8/2/)

Comment: chk7 must be available to be checked, when i tried your example on jsfiddle I was unable to check it, can you revise the code for this to work please?...@adeneo

Comment: @jeeperscreepers - you're right, the function is running on that one as well, try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E6pF8/3/) instead ?

Comment: thats now working great, many thanks for this, I will apply this to my code and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried to add this script to my page and get the following error in Firebug: $("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").not("#chk7").on is not a function. I have it in the document ready function, any ideas? ...@adeneo

Comment: That error is not related to the code above, either you changed it or you have `$("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").not("#chk7").on(...)` somewhere else in your code, and you should'nt escape the quotes, just use single quotes inside or outside the selector to seperate them.

Comment: The output from the firebug error escaped the selector values. The code is: $(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not('#chk7').on('change', function() {

    $('#chk7').prop('checked', $('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(6):checked').length == 6);

})
});

Comment: Just noticed we are using the following Jquery library: jquery-1.6.4.min.js. Noticed that your example uses 1.8 maybe this is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, `on()` only works in jQuery 1.7 or later, you'll have to use regular `click()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
$("#chk7").prop("checked", $(".chkbox").filter(function() {
    return /^chk[1-6]$/.test(this.id) && this.checked;
}).length == 6);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FbQUF/

Comment: Without button: `$("input").on("click", function() {
    $("#chk7").prop("checked", $(".chkbox").filter(function() {
        return /^chk[1-6]$/.test(this.id) && this.checked;
    }).length == 6);
});​`

Comment: These would not work for me as the name and id are not sequential...@VisioN

Answer (score 0):

If you add a specific class to the checkboxes you wanna check (let's say `need`), you could use the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) as follow:

```
$("#chk7").prop("checked", $(".need:checked").length === 6);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, The class attribute for all checkboxes including the last one is set to chkbox and cannot be changed as they are dynamically created so I guess this wouldn't work

Comment: @jeeperscreepers Then use VisioN answer, it's the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = true;
$('.chkbox').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       alert('Element with id ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' is checked');
   } else {
       alert('Element with id ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' is unchecked');
       checked = false;
   }
});

if(checked)
     $('#checkbox7').attr("checked","checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way: [Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9s2vA/97/)

```
<input id="1" name="1" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="2" name="2" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="3" name="3" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="4" name="4" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<br />
<input id="5" name="5" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" />

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
if (!$('input.paid[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
    $('input[name=5]').attr('checked','checked');
else
    $('input[name=5]').attr('checked',false);
})
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, The class attribute for all checkboxes including the last one is set to chkbox and cannot be chnaged as they are dynamically created so I guess this wouldn't work.

Comment: I noticed in your code it works one way but I need it to uncheck the last box if one of the checkboxes is unchecked.

Comment: I get this when i add your code to my page: $("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").on is not a function @Vishal Suthar