# how to delete a checkbox on condition using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have something like this:

```
<th colspan="2">Status</th>
<th class="data-name">Name</th>
<th class="data-name">Description</th>
```

The Status field has 2 values: the checkbox is 'in Use' and 'Not used'. I want to add a validation to the checkbox saying, if the status is 'in Use'-> dont delete the checkbox, else delete. here is an example:

```
 if $('.data-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked').inUse  
 { 
     alert('do not delete the checkbox');
 } 
 else 
 {
     alert('delete the checkbox');
 }
```

In short, if the checkbox is checked and the condition (if the chckbox not in use is satisfied), then delete the entire row...

here is the html: `<th class="data-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="data-selectall" /></th>
           <th colspan="2">Status</th>
            <th class="data-name">Name</th>
            <th class="data-name">Description</th>`

I'm just trying to achieve a valid delete condition:

```
if (checkbox is in use) {(dont delete)}
else {(delete)}
```

Comment: Why did you not show your entire HTML?

Comment: I'm not seeing a checkbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check to see if checkboxes are check and then check another checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109160/check-to-see-if-checkboxes-are-check-and-then-check-another-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

`if $('.data-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked').inUse`

This doesn't make any sense, if anything it should be:

`if( $('.data-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked').inUse )`

You forgot the parenthesis of the `if` statement.